# Add robots.txt to GIT repository

Tags: git, cicd

I'm working on a WordPress website that I manage via Composer. Is it a good idea to add the `robots.txt` to the GIT repository for CI/CD or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea if you wish to preserve and track its changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases i would say is a good idea. It could be that you make some changes and dont want edit file on the server etc. Or you checkout the project again and want publish ion a new server. Then there is a risk that you will forget the robots.